# Remote desktop issue

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

In my local network there are several computers. All computers are members of domain.

My computer's name is `Abs02`
Remote computer's name is `Abs01`

From my computer, `Abs02`, I am trying to access remote desktop of `Abs01` with `mstsc`.

I am getting the following error

[image]

Following picture shows remote settings of `Abs01`

[image]

The weird part of the issue is I can access all other computers. The remote settings of them is as `Abs01`. The operating systems (Windows 10 Pro) are freshly installed. I haven't done any changes in settings (Everything is by default).

Comment: uncheck the Network Level Authentication box, and see if that helps.

Comment: Last time this happened to me, it was because someone had taken the network cable out of the target computer.

Comment: Did you try looking at the firewall settings on abs01?

Comment: Also, to rule out more basic connectivity issues - 1) try to do nslookup abs01, make sure that the right IP address is listed, 2) make sure that you can ping abs01, 3) if possible install telnet and try to do telnet abs01 3389 - see if the connection can be established.

Comment: None of the prompts helped. I checked cables and didn't find anything wrong. Also, pinging is working just fine.

Comment: @cdavid Looks like you are right. It is firewall. I turned on rules for public profiles (TCP and UDP) and it has worked. Doesn't it create security issues?

Comment: Yes, especially if you are on the public internet. To mitigate those issues, you can set up IP whitelists in the firewall (from where you connect), you can enable NLA, you can enable account lockout policy etc.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your firewall is blocking your access. Try to allow remote desktop on the pc you're wanting to connect to. [This](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2010/03/allow-remote-desktop-services-and-ping-through-firewall-on-windows-server-2008-r2-or-windows-7/) explains how you have to do it on Windows 7, but it's the same for Windows 10.

On Abs01 (the remote pc), when going to your Firewall settings in the Control Panel, go to Advanced settings on the left side on your screen and select Inbound Rules.

Scroll down until you see "Remote Desktop (TCP-In)" and double click on it. There you can select "Allow Connection". Now, you should be able to remote desktop to that pc.

You can also check your outbound connections on Abs02 (the pc you're working on). It's the same method, you only have to select outbound connections instead of inbound connections.

Sometimes Windows will disable it by default (had the same problem on my work pc).

Comment: This seems to be a [link-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/388884) answer. You should provide context to all your links, otherwise the OP will have no idea what they are clicking into. Also, the link can break and the answer becomes worthless later.

Comment: added the explanation

Comment: Much better! Thank you, have a great day! +1